# Index error in python which is coming in list

Tags: python

```
   >>> L1=[1,2,3]
    >>> L1[3]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
                
   
    
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

hey I am new to python and getting an error which i have never encountered

Comment: List indexes start at 0. So the possible indexes are `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> L1=[1,2,3]
>>> L1[2]
```

check this out as it starts from 0 not with 1 so here:-1 will be at index0,2 at index1,and 3 at index2

Comment: O_o my eyes! why this formatting?

Comment: funny both have the same name but looks like different accounts